Find all partitions at a given edit distance from a reference partition of n items
Suppose we have a given partition of n items, say P, and consider the "edit distance" from this question: Edit distance between two partitions.
How can we efficiently find all partitions (of n items) at a given distance d from P?
For d=1 shouldn't be so hard, for example looping through items and moving them from their set to another (including empty set to generate a new singleton). However for d=2, applying 2 moves can takes back to P, and in general, for d>1 applying d moves in many cases could generate a partition that is at a distance <d, for example through cycles, but I can think of other ways too: swapping a pair of items in sets of equal size s (2 moves) or swapping everything but those two items (2*(s-1) moves) generate the same partition. So how can we avoid generating those partitions? I would like to avoid generating all those extra partitions and then checking the distance between them and P to remove them. If possible, I would like to find an algorithm that is designed to generate only the desired partitions.

I do not know the answer, but a technique I would consider to avoid redundant constructions of the same partition is reverse search.
